# Fix content to be displayed on specific page

Tags: positioning, page-numbering

How can I fix a content (textblock, minipage, etc.) to be on a specific page an let the main text flow from page no 1 directly to page no 3 (i.e. skip page no 2)?

It is for the impressum of a magazine resp. newspaper. It should appear on page two, top, but text is already starting at page one and should directly continue at page three.
(I guess the question is shamefully stupid).

Answer (score 7):

The package `afterpage` allows the insertion of material at the beginning of the next
page:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\afterpage{%
  \textbf{\Huge Page Two}%
  \newpage
}
\lipsum[1-9]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, it does not work. The page comes "after" the entire block (multicols) on page 4, not page 2.

Comment: That's one of the things, what MWEs are good for.

Answer (score 5):

In ConTeXt, you can use `\startposponing[<pagenum>]` to force content to appear on a specific page.

```
\starttext

\startpostponing[2] % Show content on page 2
  \startsection[title={This will appear on page 2}]
    \input ward
  \stopsection
  \page
\stoppostponing

\dorecurse{15}{\input knuth \par}

\stoptext
```

You can also use `\startpostponing[+1]` to force content to appear on the next page.

Answer (score 3):

Since package `multicol` is used, the simple version with package `afterpage` does not work. The following method uses package `atbegshi`. Page 2 is given right
after `\begin{document}` as first page. In `\AtBeginShipout` the page is not output,
but stored in a box for later use. Then the normal text follows (page 1, 3, 4, …).
If the third page is seen in `\AtBeginShipout`, the box with "page 2" is output before
the third page. Also page numbering needs a fix to skip page 2.

```
\listfiles
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{atbegshi}[2010/12/02]
\usepackage{zref-abspage}% only for counter "abspage"

\newbox\PageTwo
\AtBeginShipout{%
  % Store the first page
  \ifnum\value{abspage}=1 %
    \global\setbox\PageTwo=\box\AtBeginShipoutBox
    \AtBeginShipoutDiscard
  \fi
  % Output first page as "page 2" before page 3
  \ifnum\value{abspage}=3 %                     
    \AtBeginShipoutOriginalShipout\box\PageTwo
  \fi
}

% Fix page numbering, go directly from 1 to 3 
\makeatletter
\let\OrgStepCounter\stepcounter  
\renewcommand*{\stepcounter}[1]{%
  \expandafter\ifx\csname c@#1\endcsname\c@page
    \ifnum\value{#1}=1 %  
      \OrgStepCounter{#1}%
    \fi
  \fi
  \OrgStepCounter{#1}%
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{page}{2}
\textbf{\Huge Page Two}%
\newpage

\setcounter{page}{1}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[1-9]   
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

The example is tested with TL and MiKTeX 2.9.

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
atbegshi.sty    2011/10/05 v1.16 At begin shipout hook (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
zref-abspage.sty    2012/04/04 v2.24 Module abspage for zref (HO)
zref-base.sty    2012/04/04 v2.24 Module base for zref (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
 auxhook.sty    2011/03/04 v1.3 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
multicol.sty    2011/06/27 v1.7a multicolumn formatting (FMi)
  lipsum.sty    2011/04/14 v1.2 150 paragraphs of Lorem Ipsum dummy text
 ***********
```

Comment: I tried above code as is, but it gave errors (undefined control sequence. Page two is on page 3.

Comment: The last word in the line after `! Undefined control sequence.` is the undefined control sequence. Which versions do you use, see edited answer.

Comment: ! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...e}=3 \AtBeginShipoutOriginalShipout
\box \PageTwo \fi
l.43 \end{document}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

Comment: LaTeX Warning: You have requested, on input line 2, version
`2010/12/02' of package atbegshi,
but only version
`2008/07/31 v1.9 At begin shipout hook (HO)'
is available. 
Maybe a version problem?

Comment: You need a newer version of package `atbegshi`. It is part of bundle `oberdiek`.

Comment: Updating is so complicated, so I did just overwrite the atbegshi.sty, texhash... and it works!Thanks a lot!