# Latex forcing tikz pictures in specific pages

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex, positioning

I have a bunch of Tikz pictures that need to be inserted into specific pages of the document.  However, I do not want to go to each page and insert the appropriate tikz picture/code there. Instead, I would like to define a tex file before `\begin{document}` and then insert them all in there, so I can easily access/remove/add them. Therefore, I need a command for each tikz picture that specifies the page number they supposed to appear. There was a posted solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65943/fix-content-to-be-displayed-on-specific-page) that uses `\startposponing[<pagenum>]` command to do this. However, that command for ConTeXt and does not work in LaTeX. I was wondering is there a good solution to my problem. I am using pdfLatex. An example code is provided below:

```
\newcommand{\Mytikz1}{
\begin{textblock*}{5cm}(16.2cm,23.6cm) 
   \tikz[scale=0.7]{\spiral{12}}
\end{textblock*}
}

\newcommand{\Mytikz2}{
\begin{textblock*}{5cm}(14.2cm,23.6cm) 
   \tikz[scale=0.7]{\spiral{12}}
\end{textblock*}
}
```

Therefore I need a solution that enable me to do this:

```
Mytikz1[page3]
Mytikz2[page8]
Mytikz2[page15]
Mytikz1[page23]
```

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/506766/pin-figure-to-page-and-column-in-a-2-column-document